# Using Non-English text or string for Username display error message

Tags: asp.net, membership

I'm developing an asp.net website app that supports both English and Amharic languages. Here the problem is with amharic user registration page. when i use amharic text for user name in  CreateUserWizard control and click the button to register user , error message displayed saying "The username is already in use." when i look into users table this username is not a duplicate. I am sure for this. So help me how to make it accept amharic text for the username? Help me please.

Comment: What is the datatype of that username column? Can you show some of your code?

Comment: The data type of the username column is NVARCHAR

Comment: I'm on the 4th day to solve this. I read about a COLLATION issue but i fear the membership db may not work as it is expected to work. I tried to send the username to db like this string.Format("'N{0}'",txtUsername.Text). But ot solved

Comment: That format will just add an N to the name. An nvarchar parameter should be enough

Comment: Membership.CreateUser("amharic_text_as_username", password.Text,email.Text)
what is the right way to format this amharic text so that the function will operate successfully? Any help please

Comment: @Hans, thank you. When i assign username ="አብርሃም" and pass to the function it is not work. display msg is "The username is already in use." but this username not found in the table

Comment: I don't know any Amharic, so I don't know if it is possible for a "similar" name to exist that gets confused with this name? Anyway, you should not have to 'format' a text to get it accepted

Answer (score -1):

After a day of my post, i come with a possible solution for my question. I google alot of things on the internet and come with Encryption and Decryption. For using non English text or unicode string (that is written in a different language) as a username and also as a password ,Encrypt them at code behind inside of appropriate events during user creation and also login events before sending into a membership database. And when retrived to display them should decrypt . I found this helpful and think this can help others. Facing the same challenge. If there is another way better than this please share with me.  More on this https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx